# Como redirecionar para outra página com o botão Voltar

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Preciso "substituir" a função do botão Voltar do navegador, para quando o usuário clickar ele seja redirecionado para uma página. Já estou usando um snippet que encontrei porém o funcionamento dele não é muito consistente, e se o usuário não tiver clickado ao menos uma vez na tela, ele não funciona.

```
<script>    
    (function(window, location) {
    history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname+"#!/history");
    history.pushState(null, document.title, "");

    window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {            
        if(location.hash === "#!/history") {            
            setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('breadCurso').submit();
            },0);
        }
    }, false);
    }(window, location));
</script>
```

Estou fazendo o redirecionamento através de um formulário (ID 'breadCurso'), para que os links fiquem protegidos pelo POST, e "incluindo" as páginas através de PHP.

Comment: Encapsula a função corretamente e tenta de novo (function() { ... })(window, location)

Comment: @ruansenadev eu continuo tendo o mesmo problema de ter que clickar na tela ao menos uma vez antes. Se eu não clickar, eu sou redirecionado para a página principal.

Comment: Isso não é muito interessante, tende a deixar o usuário com raiva do site, não tem como impedir que ele use o botão, assim como não tem como bloquear o console, mais você pode alterar o histórico, assim, se ele apertar voltar, iria para uma outra pagina, mais não é bom, principalmente se for um clique acidental durante uma pesquisa no google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o localstorage para armazenar uma variavel na página que voce não quer que o usuário volte, se ele voltar e a variavel estiver definida você redireciona para outra página.

```js
if(!localStorage.getItem("verifica_se_passou_nesta_pagina")){
localStorage.setItem("verifica_se_passou_nesta_pagina","passou")
} else{
window.history.forward(); // envia para á pagina que o usuário estava
}
```

O localstorage só será apagado se o usuário limpar o histórico e o cache.

Para evitar que o refresh da página reenvie um formulário, deve-se verificar se a requisição é um POST, o exemplo a seguir retirei do [link](http://wbruno.com.br/php/diferenciar-refresh-f5-de-postsubmit/):

```
<?php
session_start();

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' )
{
    $request = md5( implode( $_POST ) );
    
    if( isset( $_SESSION['last_request'] ) && $_SESSION['last_request']== $request )
    {
        echo 'refresh';
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['last_request']  = $request;
        echo 'post';
    }
}
```

?>

```html
<form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="ae" value="ae" />
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, é sim funcional mas não é aplicável no meu problema. A minha questão maior é que sempre que atualizo ou uso o botão de voltar, ele pede para reenviar o formulário, já que estou fazendo o redirecionamento das páginas através de formulários POST, então estou tentando "substituir" a função de voltar por uma função de redirecionar, antes que a próxima página seja carregada.

Comment: Agora entendi sua questão, editei minha resposta!

Comment: Se a questão é o reenvio do POST Form, você pode usar esse pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get. Se não procure trabalhar com o objeto state disponibilizado no history e no event do popstate